# By when we can expect GA4 spreadsheet add-ons to come?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

At present, there is no spreadsheet add-on available as we have for Universal Analytics.

I wanted to know how we can automate GA4 data to spreadsheet as we do in universal analytics using spreadsheet add-on.

Comment: You can find GA4 add-on in Workspace Marketplace. It's free.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume you are referring to [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on).

I asked the team back in November 2022 if they would be creating one for Ga4 and they said they would.  They did not give me a date thought. (Im on NDA so even if they had given me a date I probably couldn't share it.  But they didn't so loop hole.) I can ask again when I have my next meeting with them.

If you want my opinion they will probably wait until the data api is out of beta and fully released before they release one.   Other wise they will have to fix bugs introduced by changes in a beta api.

You can use the Google Data api and the google sheets api in combination to extract data from google analytics GA4 your just going to have to do all the hard work yourself.

Another option would be app script but last i checked the app script version of the data api was still in Alpha so that's even worse.

Comment: Exactly, I'm talking about the same as you mentioned above.
Thanks for the update. Meanwhile I'll try to figure it out how to use Google Data api and the google sheets api in combination to extract data from google analytics GA4.

Comment: Okay due to NDA I cant give you a date but its defiantly coming.